# Query: Building a Group based on Date Email Added/Created

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, datetime, date

I'm looking to build a list segment based on people who joined my list in the past 30 days. However, when I try to check the syntax on the query below, ExactTarget gives me the following error message:

> "The query syntax is invalid. Invalid column name 'ListName'."

I have also tried running this query off ListID to no avail. Any thoughts on a fix for this one?

```
SELECT EmailAddress
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE ListName = 'Pearls'
AND DateDiff(day,DateJoined,GetDate()) <= 30
```

Comment: instead `ListName` use `LastName` in query.

Answer (score 0):

`ListName` is not a valid column in the `_Subscribers` System Data View.  The available fields can be found here: [_Subscribers](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribers/)

Perhaps you intended to query the [_ListSubscribers](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_listsubscribers/) view?  If so, you'd need to specify the ListID, which can be found in the List Properties in the SMFC interface.

**Update**

Here's a query that'll consider the date the Subscriber joined the list.  It's better to join on SubscriberID in this case:

```
select 
s.EmailAddress 
from _Subscribers s 
left outer join _Listsubscribers ls on (
    s.subscriberid = ls.subscriberid 
    and ls.listid = 170095
)
where DateDiff(day,ls.CreatedDate,GetDate()) <= 30
```

Comment: thank you, @adam! Just tried this and it worked:

select s.EmailAddress
from _Subscribers s
left outer join _Listsubscribers se
on s.EmailAddress = se.EmailAddress
where  DateDiff(day,DateJoined,GetDate()) <= 30 AND ListID=170095

Comment: `DateJoined` is not the day they were added to the list.